# What is the expected level for your characters when going to Gizamaluke's Grotto?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

I'm playing Final Fantasy IX through as I only ever played it once (and barely recall the experience), and have just left Lindblum for Gizamaluke's Grotto.

I need a little advice as my party sucks big time. Zidane is level 7 and does < 100 damage with attack. Vivi still has Fire as his only spell, which also does around 100 damage. Steiner is actually the best, doing around 200 damage..

I'm quite aware the party is weak so what kind of level should I be aiming to work toward at this point in the game? I got a Mage Masher in the previous town, but haven't come across much other decent equipment..

I'll be scanning some walkthroughs, but thought I'd see if any veterans on here might be able to offer some tips (or just reminisce about the old, great FF games!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the bestiary, the grotto holds ~lv16 mobs. I'm normally able to fight mobs a few levels higher than my character in FF games. I would shoot for level 12 - 14 before comfortably navigating the Grotto.

See [C - G] on the website below and search for "grotto"
http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/psx/ffix/bestiary2.shtml

Comment: ahh, the old school grinding, before the days of MMO grinding.

Comment: Thanks! Will aim for that kind of level and have a look and see if there's anything around that I can synthesize at this point in the game